# awsglue.utils.GlueArgumentError: argument --extra-files is required

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I am trying to run a glue job that is created with a set of DefaultArguments using boto3 and then, start the job by passing only the Job_Name argument:

```
response = boto3.client('glue').create_job(
             Name='job_name',
             Role='job_role',
             Command={
               'Name': 'glueetl',
               'ScriptLocation': 'src/glue.py',
               'PythonVersion': '3'
             },
             DefaultArguments={
               '--extra-files': 'config/config.json'
             }
           )
response = boto3.client('glue').start_job_run(JobName='job_name')
```

The issue is that I can not access the DefaultArguments of the running job itself in the glue.py like this:

```
import sys 
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv,['JOB_NAME','extra-files'])
print "The extra file is: ", args['extra-files']
```

I get the following error:

```
in getResolvedOptions
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1733, in parse_known_args
namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1957, in _parse_known_args
self.error(_('argument %s is required') % name)
awsglue.utils.GlueArgumentError: argument --extra-files is required
```

When running the job I did not overwrite the DefaultArguments and specified only the name of the flue job. Yet, it looks like I need to pass the DefaultArguments again in the *start_job_run* function, otherwise it's overwritten by default. When running the *get_job_run* on the running job I don't find the Arguments created in the definition of the glue job. Am I missing something here?